# I am unable to update an item in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Individuals user of my appplication have their Bar Information created immediately after creating their Bars. I want to enable them to be able to update their bar information but It keeps returning the error "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." I am not sure of what that means and this kind of error is weird to me.

views.py

```
def UpdateUserBar(request):
    user = request.user.id
    user_email = request.user.email
    bar = Bar.objects.get(user_id=user)
    form = UpdateBar(request.FILES, instance=bar)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateBar(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=bar)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/updatebar')
            messages.success(request, 'Bar Information Updated successfully')
        # else:
        #     return redirect('/dashboard')
        #     messages.error(request, 'Only Post method is accepted')
        else:
            try:
                pass
            except Exception as e:
                messages.error(request, "Unknown error"+ str(e))
                return redirect(request.path)
    else:
        form = UpdateBar(instance=bar)
    context = {"form":form, "user_email":user_email, "bar":bar}
    return render(request, "dashboard/super/landlord/update_bar.html", context)
```

**Note**: If i use the second else block code which was commented, it only redirects me to the dashboard and shows no error, so I am not able to know the cause of the error.

models.py

```
class Bar(models.Model):

    bar_status = (
            ("active", "active"),
            ("closed", "closed"),
            ("pending", "pending"),
        )

    user_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    opening_time = models.TimeField()
    closing_time = models.TimeField()
    status = models.CharField(choices=bar_status, default="pending", max_length=14)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/bars', default='images/bars/default.jpg')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateBar(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = '__all__'
```

updatebar.html

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.name.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="id_name" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{user.name}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="display: none;">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.user_id.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input id="id_user_id" name="user_id" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{user_email}}">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.address.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.address | attr:"class:form-control"  }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.status.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.status | attr:"class:form-control"  }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.image.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.image | attr:"class:form-control"  }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.opening_time.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.opening_time | attr:"class:form-control"  }}
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">{{ form.closing_time.label }}</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            {{ form.closing_time | attr:"class:form-control"   }}
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <center><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update Bar Info</button></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." usually means that a field that has `choices` has not been correctly submitted with one of the available choices. In this case, it means that something's wrong with the `status`, since this is the only field that uses `choices`.

Note that in `class Bar` you are defining `status` twice; the second time will overwrite the first. I'm not certain this has to do with the problem, but it *is* going to create problems at some point.

Comment: wow, that was so thoughtful of you. I have updated the question. but i still face the same error.

Comment: @coderboy You really need to reduce this code to the minimum that produces the error. For example, you have a redundant `try: pass; except...` somewhere. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example